# Recognise cyrillic or german characters in KeyEventHandler

Tags: c#, wpf

Can KeyEventHandler catch correct foreign keyboard characters?

I need to see if sentence contains certain characters while typing and German umlaut characters, Cyrillic and other should be recognized if user has that system keyboard selected.

```
this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnButtonKeyDown);

private void OnButtonKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   Sentence.Contains(e.Key.ToString());
```

For example, typing **ö** gets me "Oem3" and the same is for that button regardless which keyboard is selected.

I can not use TextBox here so KeyEventHandler is preferred.

Comment: The keys reported by KeyDown are the same anywhere in the world.  They are *virtual* keys.  The character they produce are very different, depends on the keyboard layout that the user selected.  You are using the wrong event handler, use TextInput instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to do that with `KeyEventArgs`. But you could alternatively use the `PreviewTextInput` event instead of the `PreviewKeyDown` event. E.g. like this:

```
this.PreviewTextInput += OnButtonPreviewTextInput;

...

void OnButtonPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    if ("äöüÄÖÜß".Contains(e.Text))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("German text entered");
    }
    else if (e.Text.Any(c=>0x0400 <= c && c <= 0x4FF))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Cyrillic text entered");
    }
}
```